# I keep getting 'null' at the end of what the console prints

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using DartPad and this has been happening with other if-else statements and loops, and I can't figure out why. I tried resetting the pad but to no avail, any ideas?

This is what the console prints:

> The word board is an isogram!
>
> null

This is the code:

```
void main (){
  print (isIsogram('board'));
}

isIsogram (String word){
  var splitWord = word.split('').toSet();
  if (splitWord.length == word.length) {
    print ('The word $word is an isogram!');
  }
  else {
    print ('The word $word is not an isogram');  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@fay, you can simply remove print in `main()` since it's already printing in `isIsogram`

```
void main (){
  isIsogram('board');
}

isIsogram (String word){
  var splitWord = word.split('').toSet();
  if (splitWord.length == word.length) {
    print ('The word $word is an isogram!');
  }
  else {
    print ('The word $word is not an isogram');  
  }
}
```

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The technical explanation is that all methods in Dart that aren't marked `void` have to return something, and when nothing is explicitly returned with `return X;` then `null` is implicitly returned. As such, when you `print` the return value of a non-void method that doesn't return anything, you end up printing the implicitly returned `null` value instead.

Comment: @Abion47, you're correct. I assumed OP was just testing by printing and was trying to figure out if his logics were incorrect. My intention was to let him know that he was printing twice but i understand it could've used some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`isIsogram` must have a return type to avoid printing `null`.

```
void main (){
  print (isIsogram('board'));
}

String isIsogram (String word){
  var splitWord = word.split('').toSet();
  if (splitWord.length == word.length) {
    print ('The word $word is an isogram!');
  }
  else {
    print ('The word $word is not an isogram');  
  }
  return word;
}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: This answer resolves the printing of `null` but doesn't explain why it was printing `null` in the first place.

Comment: I gave a hint in my answer. Because `isIsogram` does not have a return type so whenever this function called and it gets back to `print (isIsogram('board'));` it prints null.

Comment: But it doesn't explain _why_ it prints null. It just says that it does. I posted an explanation of why in my comment on the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes i read that! Thanks to You put that in more technical words:)

Answer (score -1):

```
void main (){
  print (isIsogram('board'));
   }

 isIsogram (String word){
  var splitWord = word.split('').toSet();
  if (splitWord.length != word.length) {
    print ('The word $word is an isogram!');
  }
  else {
    print ('The word $word is not an isogram');  
  }
  return word;
}
```